# Как в JavaFX создать поток который будет добавлять Label, пока не нажать кнопку Stop?

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx

Как в JavaFX создать поток который будет добавлять Label, пока не нажать кнопку Stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаем таймер. По расписанию добавляем лейбл. Если нажали кнопку, то ставим флаг `needStop` в `true` и больше у нас лейбл не будет выводиться.

```
public void methodName() {
    java.utit.Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {@
        Override
        public void run() {
            if (!needStop) {
                Platform.runLater(() - > addNewLabel());
            } else {
                timer.cancel(); // убираем выполнение
            }
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, new Date(), 1000); // 1000 - в секундах, как часто запускать метод `run()`
}

private void addNewLabel() {
    //логика создания и добавления лейбл
}

private void buttonClick(ActionEvent event) {
    this.needStop = true;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое) многое прояснило, но еще один вопрос, у меня код по считыванию rfid.reader() и частица кода
do { 
   if(reader.getTaglist() != null) 
     System.out.println(reader.getTaglist())
  Thread.sleep();
} while(service.isRunning());

вот я в этот код хочу закинуть label, если tagList не пустой проходить по нему и создавать label, может типо в скайпе пообщаться, естественно не бесплатно!))

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)